# How to filter ListView?

Tags: listview, react-native

I have images in Firebase and trying to load them via ListView. However I want to filter them depending on access privileges in the same table in Firebase. Columns in the table are 
1. name
2. description
3. access

I am trying to load images array only if access > 0. How do I implement that in my code or suggestions? Appreciate any help. I am a newbie by the way :-).

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    })        
}


listenForProfiles(dataRef) {
    dataRef.on('value', (snap) => {
        var images = [];
        snap.forEach((child) => {
            images.push({
                name: child.val().uploadLink,
                description: child.val().uploadDescription,
                _key: child.key
            });         
        });
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(images)
        });
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForProfiles(this.dataRef);
}
```

Comment: Anybody ? Appreciate your help!